# Tornado yield [ <list of futures> ] performs only 10 requests simultaneously

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado

I want to perform 100 requests at the same time by easy way with `yield [ list_of_futures ]`.

But this method performs only 10 requests at the time!

I prepared a short example which demostrates it, just run and you'll see requests which are performed by portions of 10 requests at the time.

Tested with debian stretch and ubuntu 16.04 with the same results.

Python 3.6.1,
tornado==4.5.1

```py
from datetime import datetime
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.gen
import tornado.web
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient


# the same for tornado and curl clients
# AsyncHTTPClient.configure('tornado.curl_httpclient.CurlAsyncHTTPClient')
http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self, **kwargs):
        yield self.write('<html><pre>')
        yield tornado.gen.sleep(5)
        yield self.finish('long page test</pre></html>')


def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        tornado.web.url('^/test', MainHandler),
    ])


@tornado.gen.coroutine
def long_request(n):
    print('long_request {n} start'.format(n=n))

    response = yield http_client.fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/test')
    yield tornado.gen.sleep(5)

    print('{date} long_request {n} finish, size {size}'.format(
        date=datetime.now(), n=n, size=len(response.body))
    )


@tornado.gen.coroutine
def requests_handler():
    print('Requests handler started')
    yield [long_request(n) for n in range(100)]
    print('Requests handler finished')


app = make_app()
app.listen(8000, '127.0.0.1')

tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().add_callback(callback=requests_handler)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, just found what it was.

Each client can perform only max_clients requests.

```py
AsyncHTTPClient.configure(
    'tornado.curl_httpclient.CurlAsyncHTTPClient',
    max_clients=100
)

AsyncHTTPClient.configure(
    'tornado.simple_httpclient.SimpleAsyncHTTPClient',
    max_clients=100
)
```

But I suppose it's not an obvious behaviour, so I suppose it should be remained here for next googlers.